# If I use the Transpurrter and abandon quest I lose all items collected?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In Monster Hunter Generations we have a new service in the beginning of the quests, which is the palico transpurrter, that brings back to village some items that we give him to get back.

If I ask him to delivery some item that I have adquired during the quest, and them abandon it (which usually returns to the state before entering the quest) those items will be lost? Or will be delivered?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this.

I had 74 Herbs in my box. I went to Jurassic Frontier via the paw pass quest, collected two herbs, gave them to the Transpurrter, then abandoned the quest.

When I went to look in my box afterwards, I still had 74 Herbs.

So it looks like the answer is **yes**, you do lose any items you gave to the Transpurrter if you abandon the quest.